# What's the option of tar that corresponds to the `arcname` option in Python `tarfile` module?

Tags: python, tar

In Python, we can specify an alternative name for a file in the archive:

```
with tarfile.open('archive.tar', 'w') as a:
    a.add('files', arcname='another_name')
```

This is done with the `arcname` parameter.

Now I'm trying to do the same thing with plain `tar` command, but I can't find the option that let me specify an alternative name.

Comment: perhaps `--strip-path` can help? not the same thing, but in some cases can be used to achieve the same goal.

Comment: @shx2 Thx. But in my case, I am specifying a completely different name.

Comment: The command does not really have that fine a control.  You tar up a directory full of files.  If you want the files to have specific names, you rename them before you start the whole `tar` process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `--transform` option if you use GNU tar.

```
$ rm test.tar
$ touch a_name
$ tar cf test.tar --transform s/.*/another_name/ a_name
$ tar tf test.tar
another_name
```

According to GNU tar(1) manpage:

> ```
>  --transform, --xform EXPRESSION
>        use sed replace EXPRESSION to transform file names
> ```

Comment: This seems like what I want. Can you explain more on your example?

Comment: @satoru, `s/.*/another_name/` is `sed`-style command: It replace matched name (`.*` matches any text) with replacement string.

Comment: @satoru, `s/.*/another_name/` is similar to Python expression `re.sub('.*', 'another_name', 'a_name')`

Comment: So if `a_name` is a directory, I can transform each file or directory name with something like `s/a_name\/(.*)/another_name\/\1`, right?

Comment: @satoru, No it will not work. sed regular expression is different from Python's. You need to escape `(`, `)` to mean group.

Comment: @satoru, And even if it match the filename, it will leave directory name itself as is.

Comment: @satoru, Try something like `--transform 's/a_name\($\|\/\)/another_name\1/'`

Comment: this is really old but worth mentioning- you don't have to use `/`. Here's an example: `--transform="s,a_name/(.*),another_name\1,"`